# Visual Basic - DropDown text not altered to reflect value

Tags: vb.net, dropdownbox

I am working in `VB` and have an event that is supposed to update a number of values in a `DropDown`, and update the text accordingly:

```
        For i As Integer = 0 To (prices.Items.Count - 1)
            If prices.Items(i).Text.Contains("£") Then
                Dim dConvertedValue = getTextAsDouble(prices.Items(i).Value) / dConversionRate
                prices.Items(i).Value = dConvertedValue.ToString()

                'should update displayable text here, but no change
                prices.Items(i).Text = (Math.Floor(dConvertedValue).ToString("N") & "$")
            End If
        Next
```

This works fine in theory, and I have stepped-through and can see that the values are changing as expected. However, the Dropdown does not update at any point.

I'm very new to VB, so it could be something as simple as a syntax error. Does anybody know why this might be?

Mark

Comment: Try adding `prices.Refresh()` or `prices.Invalidate()` when you are done, to force the dropdown to redraw itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this I have used your exact code but changed the loop to 'For each'

```
For each Item as ListItem in prices.items
    If Item.Text.Contains("£") Then
        Dim dConvertedValue = (getTextAsDouble(Item.Value) / dConversionRate)
        Items.Value = dConvertedValue.ToString()
        Items.Text = (Math.Floor(dConvertedValue).ToString("N") & " sq m")
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try. I didn't know that these two loops operated any differently from each other. Why might this make the difference?

Comment: I have no idea to be honest, one plausible explanation might be you are looping through an item rather than an index. I heve only answered on experience as it worked for me o_0

Comment: The only difference between the two loops is that `For Each` uses an iterator, therefore some functions are called at the beginning and between each iteration. Maybe these function call the dropdown to refresh itself, that would be possible...

Comment: Switching to `For Each` has got this to work, I assume those functions you mentioned are already incorporated in the iterator! Thanks for your help, gents